# MVC : How to deal with complex Model?

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, model

I am trying to apply MVC in my development (without any framework) but I have a lot of trouble. First trouble: the M!
How do you deal with complex Model where there is a deep data structure and multiple "root element"?

Here is a very simple example. Suppose our model has only two "Point". Which is the best Model implementation?

### Idea n°1: Use one entry point and getters

```
import java.awt.Point;
public class TwoPointsA {
    private final Point A = new Point();
    private final Point B = new Point();
    public Point getA() {
        return this.A;
    }
    public Point getB() {
        return this.B;
    }
}
```

### Idea n°2: Use one entry point and delegates methods

```
import java.awt.Point;
public class TwoPointsB {
    private final Point A = new Point();
    private final Point B = new Point();
    public void translateA(final int dx, final int dy) {
        this.A.translate(dx, dy);
    }
    public void translateB(final int dx, final int dy) {
        this.B.translate(dx, dy);
    }
}
```

### Idea n°3: Use multiple entry points and getters

```
import java.awt.Point;
public class TwoPointsC {
    public enum Points {
        A, B;
        private final Point value = new Point();
        public Point get() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }
}
```

### Idea n°4: Use multiple entry points and delegates methods

```
import java.awt.Point;
public class TwoPointsD {
    public enum Points {
        A, B;
        private final Point value = new Point();
        public void translate(final int dx, final int dy) {
            this.value.translate(dx, dy);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC is about seperating concerns.

The MODEL and VIEW are collections of objects.

The objects in your VIEW may have types such as BUTTON, WINDOW, TEXTAREA etc.

The objects in your MODEL have types relating to your domain such as ADDRESS, POSTCODE etc

The CONTROLLER object provides the interface into your MODEL. The VIEW objects talk to the CONTROLLER object to interact with your system.

Traditionally VIEW objects could talk directly to MODEL objects but this is not recommended.

All objects conform to OO principles and are complete objects.